# Article classification

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language

I am stuck with the idea of developing a deep learning model to find news updates for specific topic let's say invention in "autonomous driving". I have some articles labeled by experts. (label relevant/not relevant). I would like to have a contentwise similarity score for new articles on the web.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: He doesn't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

NLP is rather quite hyper-dimensional. I'd go data-driven way and use some pretrained embedder. Nowadays there're a few to choose from, like [LASER](https://engineering.fb.com/ai-research/laser-multilingual-sentence-embeddings/) from Facebook. There's unofficial [pypi](https://github.com/yannvgn/laserembeddings) lib, though it works just fine. If you want to reach seminal-like scores, there's no point in doing NLP by hand. Embedders usually cover dozens of languages, so you can feed training data in any language you want. Your models will also work for those languages out-of-the-box, even if you trained them on other languages. If you need some custom stuff, you could pick [BERT](https://github.com/google-research/bert) from Google, though you'll have to push it yourself further. It isn't really pretrained that much.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will try using LASER